# Python Counting countries in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, count

I'm writing a function that counts the number of times a country appears in a dictionary and returns the country that appeared the most. If more then one country appears the most then it should return a list of the countries.

Example dictionary:

```
{'Leonardo da Vinci': [("Portrait of Isabella d'Este", 1499, 63.0, 46.0, 'chalk', 'France'), ('The Last 
  Supper', 1495, 460.0, 880.0, 'tempera', 'Italy')], 'Pablo Picasso': [('Guernica', 1937, 
  349.0, 776.0, 'oil paint', 'Spain')]}
```

Since France, Italy, and Spain all only appear once in this dictionary the function should return

```
countries_appeared_most(dictionary1())

['France', 'Italy', 'Spain']
```

If one of those countries had instead appeared 2 or 3 times the function would return just that country. The current code I have below instead searches for the artist that appears the most but I believe a couple small changes could help me instead return the country that appears the most. Does anyone have advice on how to do this? Thanks for the help

Code:

```
def countries_appeared_most(db):
    if not db:
            return None
    maxcount = max(len(v) for v in db.values())
    themax = [k for k, v in db.items() if len(v) == maxcount]
    themax.sort()
    return themax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
counter = {}
for painting_list in db.values():
    for painting in painting_list:
        country = painting[-1]
        counter[country] = counter.get(country, 0) + 1
maxcount = max(counter.values())
themax = [k for k, count in counter.items() if count == maxcount]
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to do this without importing Counter? I should have made this clear in the question but my code cant rely on imports

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I'm getting the error counter is not defined I'll try changing the name to something else

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the values to get a list of the countries:

```
>>> [x[-1] for X in d.values() for x in X]
['Spain', 'France', 'Italy']
```

And a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) can give you the most frequent ones directly:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> countries = [x[-1] for X in d.values() for x in X]
>>> Counter(countries).most_common()
[('Italy', 1), ('Spain', 1), ('France', 1)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without counter? Sorry I should have mentioned this in the question but my code needs to be simple and not rely on imports

Comment: Sorry, but I don't answer questions with arbitrary restrictions.  The collections module is a core library, so there is no reason not to import and use it.

Comment: @warrior4223 _"my code needs to be **simple and not rely on imports**"_ - What do you mean? Part of making your code simple _is_ relying on imports. imports save you from "reinventing the wheel" each time you need a certain function/class.