# Unable to count countries in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, count

I've created a function that counts the number of times a country appears in a dictionary and returns the country that appeared the most. If more then one country appears the most then it should return a list of the countries.

Example dictionary:

```
{'Leonardo da Vinci': [("Portrait of Isabella d'Este", 1499, 63.0, 46.0, 'chalk', 'France'), 
                       ('The Last Supper', 1495, 460.0, 880.0, 'tempera', 'Italy')], 
 'Pablo Picasso': [('Guernica', 1937, 349.0, 776.0, 'oil paint', 'Spain')]}
```

Since France, Italy, and Spain all only appear once in this dictionary the function should return

```
countries_appeared_most(dictionary1())

['France', 'Italy', 'Spain']
```

If one of those countries had instead appeared 2 or 3 times the function would return just that country.

The current code I have below I think is close to the solution but I keep getting a NameError that matches is not defined. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help

Code:

```
def countries_appeared_most(db):
    matches = {}
    for painting_list in db.values():
        for painting in painting_list:
            country = painting[-1]
            matches[country] = matches.get(country, 0) + 1
            maxcount = max(matches.values())
themax = [k for k, count in matches.items() if count == maxcount]
```

Comment: [Why are you asking the same question twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599222/python-counting-countries-in-dictionary)

Comment: This is a different question I'm having new issues with the code so I'm asking what is wrong it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, look at `Counter` from collections. It already does what you're trying to do.

Secondly, your problem is your indenting. `matches` is only defined in the scope of your function, but your last line isn't indented, and therefore not considered to be part of the function.

Comment: Thank you I knew it was probably something simple causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter

# unpack the tuples in the dictionary
countries = [tup[-1] for val in painter_dict.values() for tup in val]

# create a counter, get the maximum number of appearance
counter = Counter(countries)
max_count = max(counter.values())

# pull the countries of with values equal to the max_count
appeared_most = [k for k in counter if counter[k]==max_count]
```